# Samsung GT-I9100 no storage space

Tags: samsung, storage

I have a Samsung GT-I9100 and its permanently telling me I don't have enough storage space., yet there are 11GB on the USB storage available. How do I use the USB storage?

Comment: Which version of Android do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Questions:
1. Do you mean SD storage (SD card) and not USB storage? 2. What action(s) are you trying to perform when it gives you this error message?
3. How much free space do you have on your internal storage?

If you're getting that message when you're trying to install an app, keep in mind that you can't download apps directly to your SD/external storage. You have to first download/install them on your internal storage. Then you can move them to your SD card if that option is available for the app. The same applies to downloading most types of files (documents, music, videos, etc). If your internal storage is full, you have to either delete some files or move them to the SD card to free up space on internal storage. Hope that helps!